# Center of gravity of right angle trapezoid vs rectangle

Tags: geometry, polygons

Could you please help me to find the center of gravity of a trapezoid  and a rectangle with the following measures?

[Where is the center of gravity in these two shapes?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbdnV.jpg)

Trapezoid:
a: $20$cm 
b: $17$ cm
c: $48$ cm
d: $44$cm

Rectangle:
a: $20$ cm
b: $48$ cm

Could you please also visually show me where the center of gravity of this trapezoid and rectangle would be?

Thank you.

Comment: The trapezoid measures are not right! For the rectangle it is the intersection of the diagonals. Basically you need to get an intersection of two lines that follow midpoints.

Comment: Dear Moti,
Thank you for your help. Understood regarding the rectangle but why do you say the the measures of the trapezoid are not right?

Comment: I thought about a right angle trapezoid. Which are the parallel sides? The center of gravity lies on the line that connects the middle of the parallel sides. The other line will connect the center of the parallelogram and the triangle created from the trapezoid - the intersection will be the center of gravity.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Moti.
In fact my trapezoid has only 2 right angles. The parallel sides are "a" and "b". If you click on "Where is the center of gravity in these two shapes" in my description above you shold be able to see an image of it.
I am still unable to locate the center of gravity of this shape. Can you please help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Your drawing is not right - c<d. And $3^2+44^2$ and not equal to $48^2$ implies that sides values are not right - you need to select which 3 sides you use for the right angle trapezoid.

Comment: Thank you again Moti.
The 3 sides of the right angle trapezoid are  a,b,c and they measure as in the drawing. Measure of side "d" may be wrong. Please disregard it.

Comment: Are you sure that the 48 is given and not the 44? I will draw it for the 48 but suggest you check again the data.

Comment: Did you see the answer?

Comment: Will you approve the answer? I spend sometimes for you - so you could demonstrate your appreciation this way...:)

Answer (score 0):

Following drawing is my interpretation of your question:

[image]

E, F, G, and H are mid points of the sides. M center of gravity.
I just create center of gravity of triangles for the two diagonals.
Is it clear now? Will you approve the answer?:)

Comment: Moti you have done a great job, thank you very much! Actually now that I see your drawing I understand what you meant and I apologize because I gave you a wrong information.
The 44 is given, not the 48! You were right. 
Does this change the position of the center of gravity?

Comment: It will change it slightly. I assume you could do it on your own now. Will you accept the answer?:)